# Save Image from C# into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, image, sql-server-2008, filestream

I'm trying to save a picture into my SQL Server database but it's not working.

The `Picture` column in my `Customers` table is of type `image` and I'm trying to pass a byte array with the picture to the `Picture` column

My code is something like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my working connection string");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Customers", conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet("Customers");

adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Then I create a byte array for the image:

```
string path = null;
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.ShowDialog();

path = fileDialog.FileName;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte[] picArray = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(picArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
```

This how I pass values to the database:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
row["Id"] = "ID";
row["Name"] = "NAME";
row["Picture"] = picArray;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

adapter.Update(ds);
```

The problem is this line:

```
row["Picture"] = picArray;
```

It doesn't send the picture, but the array has the picture...

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: I know, but it's for a project which the database is given and I have to use it as it is. So I have to keep with the image type.. :( But as I said the problem is how do I pass the values of my byte array to row["Picture"], knowing that this Column is sql image type...

Comment: Is this the complete code around the connection?  Are the connection and adapter calls all wrapped in using statements?

Comment: @DanSnell @marc_s  it's almost the complete code, everything is working, my project is almost finished, except the only thing that is not working is how do my byte array that contains the picture goes into the `row["Picture"]` which is sql image type..... Am I missing something? or do I need to convert it or something? :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the database with your changes to the `DataSet`?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("my working connection string");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Customers", conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// Create command builder. This line automatically generates the update commands for you, so you don't 
// have to provide or create your own.
SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

// Set the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey because Fill will not cause primary
// key & unique key information to be retrieved unless AddWithKey is specified.
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

adapter.Fill(ds, "Customers");

// .... Code to fill the picArray....

DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
row["Id"] = "ID";
row["Name"] = "NAME";
row["Picture"] = picArray;
ds.Tables["Customers"].Rows.Add(row);

adapter.Update(ds, "Customers"); //Update the changes to the database
```

Comment: I am.. because row["Id"] and 
row["Name"] work. These two rows are updated to the database, but the "row["Picture"] = picArray;" isn't updating. So the Column "Picture" keeps the NULL value in the database. I also have the SqlCommandBuilder, I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the problem! :D

What @DanSnell said made me think of what I was doing wrong.

Since the code for the connection and the adapter is just fine, I found that instead of passing through a parameter the byte array containing my image, I was passing a `null byte array`

That's why when I add the byte array to the new row `row["Picture"] = picArray;`, the column Picture didn't receive any value, just a null value.

**Correcting just the way of passing the byte array to inside of my class solved the problem.**

I didn't changed any of the code above, so it may help someone who wants to *Save an Image from C# into SQL Server database*